# Return data with errors while validating data with stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have an employee table of following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Email VARCHAR(35) UNIQUE,
    Phone VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE
    city FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES City(Id)
)
```

Before inserting data into the table, I want to validate my data using a stored procedure.

The stored procedure needs to accept many rows and return data along with errors. So, I created a user-defined table type `tblTypeEmployee` which I will pass to stored procedure.

```
CREATE TYPE tblTypeEmployee AS TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Email VARCHAR(35),
    Phone VARCHAR(50),
    City VARCHAR(50)
)
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spBulkImportEmployee
    (@tblEmployeeTableType [dbo].tblTypeEmployee READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @EmployeeErrors AS tblTypeEmployee;

    INSERT INTO @EmployeeErrors (email, phone, city)
        SELECT
            CASE 
                WHEN (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Employee 
                      WHERE email = email) > 0 
                    THEN 'Email already exist' 
            END AS email,
            CASE 
                WHEN (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Employee 
                      WHERE phone = phone) > 0 
                    THEN 'Phone no. already exist' 
            END as phone,
            CASE 
                WHEN (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM City 
                      WHERE cityName = city) < 1 
                    THEN 'Invalid city name' 
            END as city,
        FROM 
            @tblEmployeeTableType

    SELECT * FROM @EmployeeErrors;
END
```

This procedure gives me all the validation errors. But I want data along with errors. So, that I can display that message in a table in the frontend. For example: If a user gives email as `abc@gmail.com` and phone no. as `123456789`, then I should get `abc@gmail.com - already exist`, `123456789 - already exist`.

How to approach this problem?

Comment: Define a table variable with 2 columns, DataValue and ErrorMessage and insert a row for each error, then select from that at the end of your proc.

Comment: If the user inserts 3 records, and at worst case if all the column values are invalid then there would be 6 records in table variable. This will not be an efficient one

Comment: Actually it is the most efficient solution because it scales like that. Using columns is a bad design

Comment: In fact there is no reason to inset into a table to select again, just write a select that returns the results you want.

Comment: If you prefer 6 columns, value, error 1-3 then do it that way. Totally up to you.

Comment: Just means you had to vode for a set number of values you are validating, whereas a row per error will automatically scale if you add another value later

Comment: This idea doesn't make sense at all. Define unique constraints / foreign keys, that's what they are used for. If you want errors to be loged, that's a job for your application (which of course could even check whether the command which would cause the error should be executed at all).

Comment: If you want your Frontend to display an error message in case of an invalid insert command for your employees table, execute those selects in your application and show a meaningful message there rather than abusing procedures. Or let your application catch violations of unique constraints / foreign keys and show which one has been violated.

Comment: You could also construct your messages like `CONCAT('Email already exists for "', email, '".')`, but I think a design that has dedicated columns for message, value, and maybe even id would be a better approach. As a side note, be aware that conflicts could also exists between the new records, which wouldn't be detected using the above logic.

Comment: This seems an unusual way to do input validation. Since it doesn't associate the error messages with any particular record (Employee `Id`), just a column, and you're accepting multiple rows of input, how will the end user know which record they've actually keyed incorrectly? It seems like the application UI should be doing this validation itself, either by querying the database tables directly or by consulting its local caches. If you want to persist with this approach it should return rows with `(Id, FieldName, ErrorMessage)` so that appropriate input grid cells can be painted with errors.

Comment: Aside: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) rather than getting an exact [`count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Comment: @HABO - In general, yes. An exists() subquery could stop at the first match, while a count would continue to the end. (There is the possibility that the query optimizer might recognize and optimize for the "count > 0" pattern, but I wouldn't count on it.) If an index is available, the cost of an index range seek and count is likely pretty small. Lastly, for this usage where the normal expected result is zero, the difference is probably negligible.